# How to display multiple images from the database in html.erb?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

So basically what I would like is to know what the ruby code is to display an image from the database. Here's an example. Let's say I want to see product id:1's page - it should display the designated image correlated with that id number. Now if I want id:2 it should display that image that correlates with that number. All of this will be on a single show.html.erb page. I am lost, please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On ERB first you will need access to all the `Product` records you need to display images for.

Quick and Dirty for demo sake you can have that access like so:

```
Product.find(1)
Product.find(2)
Product.find(3)
```

Now assuming you have `image_url` column for every product that stores the URL for the image, you can display the image like so:

```
<%= image_tag(Product.find(1).image_url) %>
<%= image_tag(Product.find(2).image_url) %>
<%= image_tag(Product.find(3).image_url) %>
```

However in real world scenario its better if you have products coming in as a array from the controller and then you iterate over that array variable `@products` then in your ERB like so:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
<% end %>
```

In case if each of the product has multiple images and assuming you have the one to many relationships setup correctly in the database your ERB code may look something like this

```
<% @product.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag(image.url) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your images are titled in a way that matches your product's id:

```
<%= image_path("product_#{@product.id}.jpg") %>
```

Note: `image_path` is a helper method.

Comment: What if the image is a url? - There's also 5,000 of them

Answer (score 0):

generally you should have a string attribute on your object pointing at the url of the image. i believe the paperclip gem facilitates this. the method of injecting the id might work, or it might quickly become too complicated a solution as your images build up.